# Google oauth satellizer uriredirect 404 error

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, satellizer

I'm trying to integrate satellizer into my Angular app using Ui router, satellizer requires that I set a redirectUri.

My question is, how do I allow this redirect to access my routes, i keep getting, 404 for the URL:
://domain:8181/?code=4/QWNlg9j47Hq.......

Not sure what I should set the redirectUri to.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a forward slash in you query parameter (code). I think that is why you get a HTTP 404.